# Property [stock] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, model

In My **Cart** Model I have Relation with **Product** Model.In **Product** Model I Have Relation with **Product_attribute** Model.
But I have No relation With **Product_attribute** Model.
In this Case, I Write this code to access `Product_attribute` Model.

```
$getCartDetails = Cart::with('product.product_attribute')->where('id',$id)->first();
```

thats works fine.I acess **Product** and **Product Attribute** Data

Now i want to count **product_attribute** *stock*,similar way want to count **cart**  *quantity*.
if `Product_attribute->stock >= Cart->quantity` ,I update carts table otherwise not

Thats why I write this code

```
   public  function updateCartQuantity($id,$quantity)
   {
       $getCartDetails = Cart::with('product.product_attribute')->where('id',$id)->first();

      if($getCartDetails->product->product_attribute->stock->sum() >= $getCartDetails->quantity->sum()) {

           DB::table('carts')->where('id', $id)->increment('quantity', $quantity);
           return back()->with('success', 'product Quantity in the cart Updated Successfully!');
       }else{
       return back()->with('error', 'Required Product Quantity is not available!');
         }


   }
```

[image]

Comment: try `dd($getCartDetails->product->product_attribute->stock)` probably you can't reach stock.

Comment: same problem.Property [stock] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: when i use this,,,,, i acces product and product_attribute data  ` $getCartDetails = Cart::with('product.product_attribute')->where('id',$id)->first();  `

Comment: try `$getCartDetails->product->product_attribute()->stock->sum()` instead of `$getCartDetails->product->product_attribute->stock->sum()` Still you get error, try `dd($getCartDetails->product->product_attribute)`

Comment: to use dd($getCartDetails->product->product_attribute) , I get all data of product_attribute

Comment: `dd($getCartDetails->product->product_attribute()->stock)` when you use that get stock data or ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218378/discussion-between-tareq-ahmed-and-xnojustice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check by

```
$check_qty =    DB::table('product_attribues)->where('product_id',$getCartDetails->product_id)->where('size',$getCartDetails->size)->first();
```

$check_qty will give you stock qty based on carts table product_id and Size. After you use a If condion for check with updated qty and stock qty.

**Because You can find product stock from product_attribues table based on product_id and Size**

Answer (score 0):

See the error, it says `property stock doesn't exist on the collection instance.`

Just check the relation once. As I can understand from the name the product might have multiple product_attributes associated to it(`One to many relation`). That might be the reason for the property does not exist on collection error. And you're trying to access a model's property on a collection which should not be the case.

EDIT:

`$getCartDetails->product->product_attribute->sum('stock')`  . This is what you need for your if condition. It will get you the sum of the stock property of all the instances of your collection.  Here's the reference https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sum